# Adding user and password to Sql Server database

Tags: sql-server-2005

My connection string defined in Web.Config currently indicatea no user or password is needed:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CinemaxConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinemax;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I would like to add user and password, like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CinemaxConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinemax;User=cinemax; Password=abc"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Obviously, this requires changing some settings **in Sql Server to add user and password**. What is the best way to do this? I specify I have Sql Server 2005 Express and the **current authentcation mode is "Sql Server and Windows Authentication"**.
Thank you in advance for your help.
It would be nice to see a double take on this: user-interface and code solution.

Comment: Will it not work if you just use ;uid=cinemax;pwd=abc - it's set up for Sql Server authentication?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but I need help in how to set it up.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set anything up that I'm aware of, unless you mean you haven't set up the user as Rajesh has shown how? Actually you have a typo in your connection string, it should be: Data Source=PCName\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Cinemax;User ID=cinemax;Password=abc (note 'User ID')

Comment: It worked by typing just "User" so perhaps both variants are valid. Thank you cheeseweasel!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The below statements would do the job for you.

```
CREATE LOGIN cinemax WITH PASSWORD = 'abc';

GO

CREATE USER cinemaxUser FOR LOGIN cinemax

GO

GRANT SELECT TO cinemaxUser

GO

GRANT INSERT TO cinemaxUser

GO

GRANT UPDATE TO cinemaxUser

GO

GRANT DELETE TO cinemaxUser

GO
```

Comment: Great, thank you Rajesh, it worked, and I'm glad with the coding solution - which I prefere more than the interface. I had to restart the mysql service for this to work, and then the site gave an error because I didn't have "execute permissions" on a procedure. I solved that from the interface by selecting all permissions. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I also had to restart Visual Studio because it gave this error: "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)" - which vanished after the restart. Now all works perfectly.

Comment: GRANT EXECUTE TO "SP_Name". After changing any permission settings, It is good idea to restart the services coz sometimes it will still hold the previous settings.

Comment: As far as the transport-level error, this is caused by your software trying to use a connection that is closed that it thinks is open.  All you have to do is run it again and it works because when the error happens, it also closes the connection in your software and the connection is remade when you next try to do whatever you are doing.

Comment: It works. If you need to create user with bypassing the password strength policy, use this: CREATE LOGIN cinemax with Password ='weak', CHECK_POLICY = OFF